# Embed Corona app within an iOS/Android app

Tags: android, ios, coronasdk

I have an existing iOS and Android app. Both are developed with the official iOS SDK / Android SDK respectively using UIViewcontrollers/Activities.

I have source code for a game built using Corona (but I am not familiar with Corona at all). I am wondering if it's possible to 'embed' this game within the both apps? Or does corona generate a stand alone executable and it's not possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To do that you would need to get [CoronaCards](http://coronacards.com/) Currently only available for iOS and in beta for Android. With Corona Enterprise you can do the oposite, embed native functionalities into Corona.

I am in the same situation and I am waiting eagerly for the launch of CoronaCards for Android.